# Windows PowerShell errors

Tags: powershell-2.0, office365

I am trying to connect to [Office 365](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_365) using Windows PowerShell 2.0.  I can't run the following commands as I get an error:

> import-module MSOnline
>   connect-msolservice

Without the connect cmdlet working, I cannot connect to my Office 365 instance. I've tried this already on two separate computers, and I get the same error in both cases. Once the computer is running Windows XP and the other is running Windows 2008 R2.

Some background. I've installed the PowerShell module available from here:

```
Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell 32-bit
Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell 64-bit
```

I installed SIA (Microsoft Online Services Module for Windows PowerShell) from here:

```
Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant 32-bit
Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant 64-bit
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Import-Module` is working it means the cmdlets are imported to PowerShell. Try this one:

```
Import-Module -MsonlineExtented -Force
```